# installation of mechanize in python2

Tags: python, pip

I have python2 and python3 both. When I run

```
pip --version
```

> pip 21.0.1 from /home/istiak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

```
└─$ python2 --version     
    Python 2.7.18
```

I have some code of Python2. Which written in weird way ~ I think bash. Here's the [git repo](https://github.com/AngelSecurityTeam/BluForce-FB). So, I want to run the project by python2 while I run the program by python3 I get the following error

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("""
>
> \033[0)?

I could fix them. While they are written in weird way. So, how can I edit them..? That's why I want to run that program by python2. When I run the program by python2 I get an error `ImportError: No module named mechanize`. I have mechanize installed in Python3. When I try to install by pip2. I get following error

> Command 'pip2' not found, did you mean:
> command 'pip' from deb python3-pip
> command 'nip2' from deb nip2
> command 'pip3' from deb python3-pip
> Try: sudo apt install

I tried to install pip2 also. `sudo apt-get install python2`. `sudo apt-get install python2-pip`. Although I am not getting pip2. How can I install mechanize in python2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for Ubuntu.

> Command 'pip2' not found

You need to install `pip2` (packaged for Ubuntu Xenial and Bionic):

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Or use the following command (Other than Xenial and Bionic):

```
sudo apt install python2   # already done
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

To install `mechanize`:

```
pip2 install mechanize
```

or:

```
python2 -m pip install mechanize
```

Comment: It worked.. But, Could you please explain the curl command..? I know that it copy and paste/download and save the file... But, I don't know how curl works(I think something like git clone)..

Comment: @GameStakes `curl` will download file from the specified URL then using the `--output` option, it will save the downloaded file to `get-pip.py`.

Answer (score 0):

`pip2` is not included in the package repository of certain distros (including Ubuntu 20.04) already. To install, run [this script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) as `sudo`.

Also, the script seems not in `bash`, but rather just the old Python 2, which uses the `print` statement instead of its function counterpart in Python 3. If this is the only problem, you can just use a regex to replace the lines.

Comment: As I said those codes are written in bash...! https://github.com/AngelSecurityTeam/BluForce-FB/blob/master/bluforcefb.py

Comment: @GameStakes that's an obfuscated Python script. Here's the decoded content if you want: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MknHhrrZsG/ You can just change `eval(compile(base64.b64decode(eval('\x74\x72\x75\x73\x74')),'<string>','exec'))` to `print(base64.b64decode(trust))` to get the actual script instead of running it.

Comment: @muru How to install `cookielib`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737908/13146129   https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405294/13146129 I am getting that No module named `cookielib` I tried this `pip install browser-cookie3` According to some documentation there's no cookielib in python3.. What to do now..?

Comment: @GameStakes It is just renamed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405096/python-3-2-cookielib/8405294